# Error getting images to show up in Symfony 1.4.8

Tags: image, symfony1, directory

*Note: It was tough deciding whether this belonged here or ServerFault, but it seemed like a programming problem, so if it's out of place, feel free to migrate it.*

I downloaded the sandbox of Symfony 1.4.8 and copied the files to my webserver. Unfortunately, when I try to access `/symfony/sf_sandbox/web/` (where I installed it), I get the following:

[image]

It seems like the images aren't showing. According to the text:

> If you see no image in this page, you may need to configure your web server so that it gains access to the `symfony_data/web/sf/` directory.

However, when I try to locate the folder referenced above, it does not exist:

```
  sf_sandbox
    web
      css/
      images/
      js/
      uploads/
      frontend_dev.php
      index.php
      robots.txt
```

As you can see, there is no `sf/` directory under `web/`. What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I am installing this on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit using Apache.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the images are located in the Symfony source directory.

I would try creating a symbolic link in the web folder called **sf**  pointed to the following:
**lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf**

It should have access to the needed images at that point.

Answer (score 2):

This is done by indicating the right path in the Alias directive in your apache configuration:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Just replace "/home/sfprojects/jobeet" with your project's path and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This page shows the apache config to set up a new project correctly. 
There are also important security notes for your webapp.

[Symfony Documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/05-Web-Server-Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy the whole sf folder to the web folder. In my case i copied c:\wamp\www\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\data\web\sf\ to c:\wamp\www\jobeet\web. Hope that makes sense