# Symfony Missing sf folder

Tags: symfony, pear

This question is not really related to programming, but I dont know where else I should ask it.

I just installed Symfony on Xampp for windows, now I struggle getting it to work because it is missing the `project/web/sf` folder and I can't find anything about it on the internet.

The missing of this folder causes me to lose the css files and images ect.

I installed Symfony via Pear and then just got a clean project using `symfony generate:project projectname`

**[edit]:** this is how my homepage looks after loading;
[image: Homepage]

**[edit 2]:** Printscreen of version number seen on `web/app_dev.php` (which is one of the few pages working correctly)

[image: Prtscreen 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from your "3 methods of installing" you have mixed multiple versions of Symfony into one installation. The `symfony_data/web/sf` problem [is unique to Symfony 1.x **only**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796583/error-getting-images-to-show-up-in-symfony-1-4-8). Symfony2 does not use the `web/sf` structure, and instead utilizes `web/bundles/framework` for framework assets.

This makes sense since [the PEAR channel isn't supported for Symfony anymore](http://pear.symfony.com/) (see the big red header?) Plus, you can only get Symfony 2.x by explicitly using `pear install symfony2` (not `pear install symfony`). You [may be using the old PEAR channel located here](http://pear.symfony-project.com/) (see how they're all 1.x versions?) and [symfony-project.com redirects to symfony.com/legacy](http://symfony-project.com/)

So now when you access `app.php` you get Symfony 1.x, and when you access `app_dev.php` you get the newest version of Symfony ~2.5. This makes things very confusing for both you and us.

### What's the fix?

Start over. Remove the project folder and its contents entirely. [Then follow these installation instructions (I've condensed them for you):](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html)

1. Start in your desired project folder.
2. `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
3. `php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition ./ '2.5.*'`
4. `php composer.phar install`

Comment: I have executed the commands you said, and followed some basic tutorials (as you can tell im totaly new to symfony or actually the entire MVC thingy) and well, I dont know how but I got it working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must make an **alias** on your web server apache, like this example:

```
# Be sure to only have this line once in your configuration
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080

# This is the configuration for your project
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, as the folder `sf` is not existing anywhere in my project.

Comment: in the project home directory don't exist the folder `lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf`? How do you installed the framework?

Comment: First: It isn't symfony 1. I have tried 3 methods of installing, the manual zip, pear, and composer

Comment: sorry but the command you posted (and screenshot) is related to the version 1.x of the framework. Check with the command `symfony -V` for symfony1. Let me know